# Changing a long[] into a Set. Error message: The method addAll in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Long>, long[])

Tags: java, arrays, collections, set, hashset

I was asked in a homework assignment to create a method in an existing program, called noDups(), that removes duplicates from a previously sorted array without disrupting the order. The question also states it must be an algorithm with O(N) and make sure no item was moved more than once, no matter how many duplicates there are.

I initially tried a nested for-loop to cycle through and remove duplicates but figured out that was O(N^2). I learned you can solve this problem with a Set. I tried writing the method to take in the long[] (the type of array the program uses) array and convert it to a set, since a set only contains unique values:

```
public long[] noDups(long[] target) { //Method for removing duplicates

        Set<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();
        Collections.addAll(set, target);

        return target;
}
```

I keep getting the error stated in the title:

> "The method addAll(Collection, T...) in the type
>   Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Set, long[])"

Before my method looked like this but I had a different error:

```
public void noDups(long[] target){

    Set<long> set = new Hashset<long>(Arrays.asList(target));
```

Am I initializing the Set wrong? Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the error or lead me in the right direction to convert a long[] to a Set. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is sorted, you shouldn't need a nested for loop.  You should be able to walk through the array once, and only add the item if it's different than the previous.

```
List<Long> newList = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Long l : target) {       
   if(newList.isEmpty() || !l.equals(newList.get(newList.size()-1))) {
      newList.add(l); 
   }
}
```

newList should contain all the entries without any duplicates.

I don't have a compiler handy to test this but hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix primitives and wrappers the way you're trying to -- in particular, `Collections.addAll` would only accept a `Long[]`, not a `long[]` in that case.

Accept that you'll need to do some loops to convert back and forth.  You'll need to loop over the array and add the elements one by one to the `Set`, and then create a primitive array and loop over the set to put elements into it.

(Or you could just use `Long[]` everywhere you're using `long[]` now, but that'd be inefficient and I'd avoid it in your place.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. As others have explained, you cannot have a `Set<long>` only `Set<Long>` (*boxed* `long`, see *auto-boxing* in Java), and you cannot add all elements of a `Long[]` to a `Set<Long>` using the `addAll` method.
2. Since you must preserve the order of the numbers, adding all values at once to a set would not help. That would filter out duplicates, but you would lose the ordering.
3. Since the input array is already sorted, you don't actually need any additional data structures to remove duplicates.

Here's an `O(n)` technique to arrange the unique values at the start of the array, and then make an efficient copy of the array, cutting off the end part of the array that is no longer needed:

```
long[] noDups(long[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return nums;

    int pos = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if (nums[j - 1] != nums[j]) {
            nums[pos++] = nums[j];
        }
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(nums, pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates form array, you don't need to use `HashMap`, you can just use Java 8 stream API. i.e.

```
 long[] dups = new long[]{1,2,3,4,4,4};
 long[] noDups = Arrays.stream(dups).distinct().toArray();
```